# проблема нажатия на кнопку selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

Всем привет, пишу код на питон (web автоматизация), возникла проблема, нужно чтобы на сайте тиктока нажалась кнопка "войти", поиск по видимости и способности нажать производил по class name с помощью try except для обработки исключений. Итак, после запуска скрипта заходит в браузер и на сайт но кнопка не нажимается, хотя я скопировал class name из html кода страницы, дальше выдает ошибку TimeoutException
даже с модулем except, буду рад любой помощи по решению этой проблемы вот код

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\\Users\\Fores\\OneDrive\\Рабочий 
стол\\files\\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.tiktok.com")
try:
 box =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.CLASS_NAME, "login-button jsx-193545642 tiktok-btn-pc tiktok-btn-pc-medium tiktok-btn-pc-primary")))
button =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.CLASS_NAME, "login-button jsx-193545642 tiktok-btn-pc tiktok-btn-pc-medium tiktok-btn-pc-primary")))
box.send_keys()
button.click()
  except TimeoutException:
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.CLASS_NAME, "login-button jsx-193545642 tiktok-btn-pc tiktok-btn-pc-medium tiktok-btn-pc-primary")))
button.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='login-button "
                                   "jsx-193545642 tiktok-btn-pc tiktok-btn-pc- 
                                    medium"
                                   "tiktok-btn-pc-primary']")
button[0].click()
```

Вот рабочее решение.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#main > div.jsx-1217828260.header- 
container.white.middle > div > div.jsx-2365341634.menu-right > button')
```